# How to create csv file bigger than you RAM using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bigdata, export-to-csv

How can I create a CSV file bigger than my RAM memory using Python (and possible Pandas)? I'm thinking about something like 'append to csv' without loading the whole csv file into the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a file object and write the dataframe to that object continually

```
with open('final.csv', 'a') as f:
    while True:
        #code to create df and break when finished
        df.to_csv(f)
```